# Relationship between the model, experimental design and data collection

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, experiment-design

When changing the model to a more sophisticated do we **ALWAYS** need to change the design experiment and/or collecting more data?

For example, after fitting a multiple linear model to the data, I checked the model fit by plotting the ordinary residuals (the residuals without normalization) vs. the fitted values and found a pattern in the plot. There's quite a good reason to suspect there's an interaction between the regressors and so I decided to move to a more sophisticated model. In such case, do I **ALWAYS** have to change the experimental design and/or collect more data to fit the new model in.

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: @MaartenBuis sorry I missed you comment, it comes from one book I was reading at the time, which I still think it's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it would be best practice to use separate data to select a model (your decision to include interaction) and to fit it afterwards (for inference), it is often not done. In fact, before [LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_data_sets) was invented (also after), statisticians systematically searched the data for variables and interaction to include in the model in a way that corresponds to the approach you describe: forward selection. The [Wikipedia article on stepwise regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression) includes critizism of the method and links to papers discussing the consequences, also of reusing the same data for inference.

This can be seen as data dredging, and in cases where you have big data or new data are cheap it should be really avoided. Big data are therefore routinely [divided into subsets used for model selection / validation (cross validation :-)) and inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_data_sets).
However, in situations where data sets are small and expensive, you need to take it from the pragmatic side and continue with the same data. In your case, you did not perform a systematic search for terms to include in the model, but detected a bad fit from the residual plot. This should be acceptable, in particular if the interaction term in the larger model tests significant with a very low p-value.

You could explore the consequences of overfitting when there is no interaction roughly by a simulation from the model with no interaction effect, and fitting a model with interaction and without. Use the results from the model with interaction only when interaction is very significant (as in your data).